# append without selector

Tags: jquery, append

is it possible to do an append without specifying a selector

so in html  I have an arbitrary element and inside that I call a function that will append content inline

so html looks like this

```
  <!-- stuff before -->
    <fieldset>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    get_content();
                });
        </script>
    </fieldset>
  <!-- stuff after -->
```

then in a js file that gets loaded  I have the get_content() function like this

```
  function get_content(){
        $.append('<div id="some_id"></div>');
  }
```

currently I get an error saying append is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript won't write out code in the way you're trying to do it here. JavaScript is separate from content and works with the *entire* document, so placing JavaScript in your markup where you want it to appear won't do anything unless you use `document.write(...)`, which is considered one of the worst things you can use in JavaScript.

Instead, you should do this:

Your markup would look like this:

```
<!-- stuff before -->
<fieldset id="elementToAppendTo">

</fieldset>
<!-- stuff after -->
```

Then your script could look like this (it can go anywhere)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    get_content();
});
</script>
```

And then you can use your `get_content()` function to append stuff.

```
function get_content(){
    $("#elementToAppendTo").append('<div id="some_id"></div>');
}
```

Comment: hmm was trying not to use id or class but looks like that is the best option

Answer (score 0):

It's not very pretty but I guess you could do this;

```
function get_content(){
  document.write($('<div><div id="some_id"></div></div>').html());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the old days this would be accomplished by `document.write()`:

```
  <!-- stuff before -->
    <fieldset>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           document.write(get_content());
        </script>
    </fieldset>
  <!-- stuff after -->

function get_content(){
  return '<div id="some_id"></div>';
}
```

But really `document.write` is not the way jQuery works. Try this way:

```
function get_content(){
  return 'your real content';
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#some_id').html(get_content());
});


  <!-- stuff before -->
    <fieldset>
       <div id="some_id"></div>
    </fieldset>
  <!-- stuff after -->
```